# How to debug Node + Socket.io CPU Issues, doing nothing but connections 100% cpu

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, websocket, socket.io

```
I'm running a Node Socket.io server with Express with docker compose
```

and client side is vue.js. The service is running well, but the CPU grows 100
and stays, i'm every time doing restart to my docker compose,still after 5 minutes cpu reaches jumping 100%.. I don't know what to check since there's laterally nothing but the most basic stuff..client and server connection and disconnect works perfect,all events is working good but i don't know which way i ll focus to find my bugs.

```
Here are my backend code socket code.



                                         


import { verifyToken } from './middleware/auth';
import Socket from './components/services/socket';


const app = express();

const socketPort = process.env.SOCKET_PORT || 8001;
const io = require('socket.io')(socketPort);

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(port, () => {
  log.info(`HTTP server is running  on port ${port}
Socket service running  on port ${socketPort}
Process Pid: ${process.pid}`);
});

const socket = new Socket(io);
socket.modelLoaded();

socket.js file______________

import { socketTokenVerification } from './../../middleware/auth';

export default class {
  constructor(io) {
    this.io = io;
    this.connections = {};
  }
  addConnection(socket) {
    if (this.connections[socket.user_id]) {
      this.socketDisconnect(this.connections[socket.user_id]);
    }
    this.connections[socket.user_id] = {
      id: socket.id,
      isAuthenticated: true,
      user_id: socket.user_id
    };
  }

  removeConnection(socket) {
    delete this.connections[socket.user_id];
  }

  socketDisconnect(socket) {
    if (this.io.sockets.connected[socket.id]) {
      this.io.sockets.connected[socket.id].disconnect(true);
    }
  }

  modelLoaded() {
    const { io, connections } = this;
    io.on('connection', socket => {
      const authData = socketTokenVerification(socket);
      if (authData.error) {
        io.to(socket.id).emit('error', {
          message: authData.message
        });
        this.socketDisconnect(socket);
        return;
      }
      const { user_id } = authData;
      socket.user_id = user_id;
      this.addConnection(socket);
      User.connected(socket.user_id);

      socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        this.removeConnection(socket);
        User.disconnect(user_id);
        this.socketDisconnect(socket);
 Object.keys(io.sockets.connected).length);
      });




Client side code.



import io from 'socket.io-client';

 socket = io(ENDPOINT, {
      transports: ['websocket'],
    });
    socket.on('connect', () => {
      console.log('conected');
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
      console.log('disconnected');
    });
    socket.on('reconnect', () => {
      console.log('reconnect');
    });
    socket.on('receive_message', (receiveMsg) => {
   console.log(recMsg, 'mes');
    });
    socket.on('error', (err) => {
      console.log(err, 'err');
    });
  },
beforeDestroy() {
    socket.disconnect(true);
  },
```

Comment: Does the console log show any events getting repeated?

Comment: No events emitted and listening each other well and none of the events are repeated

Comment: Maybe the problem doesn't reside in your snippet, but in whatever you took out to shorten it.